# PowerShell: извлечь из файла *.cer сертификаты УЦ и установить их

Tags: windows, powershell, сертификат

Есть задача: есть файл сертификата пользователя *.cer (для электронной отчетности).

Нужно:

извлечь из него ссылку на корневой сертификат и список отзывов УЦ; 
устанавливать каждый из них в реестр, указывая конкретный путь.

Хотелось бы скрипт на PowerShell, который принимает на вход сертификат пользователя и автоматом будут установлены куда 
надо сертификат УЦ и список отзывов.

Возможно ли такое сделать?

Comment: `Import-Certificate`?